# When applying modification rule on Second Order Inhomogenous D.E, what are the conditions to add x on the Yh?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In this picture, I don't understand the reason behind the application of modification rule. Can somebody please help? [image: Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y''+3y'+\frac 9 4 y=-10e^{-3/2x}$$
$$r^2+3r+\frac 94=0 \implies \Delta =9-9=0$$
$$r_1,r_2=-\frac 32$$
So the solution of the homogeneous equation is:
$$y(x)=c_1e^{-3/2x}+c_2xe^{-3/2x}$$
Since $e^{-3/2x}$ and $xe^{-3/2x}$ are both solutions of the homogeneous equation, you have to try $$y_p=Ax^2e^{-3/2x}$$ for the particular solution.